# How did Butch manage to open the cab door with his boxing gloves on?

Tags: pulp-fiction

In *Pulp Fiction*, how did Butch manage to open the cab door with his boxing gloves on? Esmeralda was in the driver seat when he got in. He was still wearing his red boxing gloves.

[image: Butch and Esmeralda Cab Scene]

Answer (score 2):

[The same way Strongbad types wearing boxing gloves](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k3VH9ATkTO0)

In all seriousness, Butch clearly planned a quick getaway.  Esmeralda may have left the door open for him or he climbed through the window.  It is not a critical detail to the plot so I don't expect Quentin Tarantino lost any sleep over this.

Comment: Haha. I doubt he will too. I’ve watched this movie a dozen times and never noticed this. Then I watch it with my 18 year old (his first watch) and he notices this. I just thought it was interesting is all. I thought maybe I missed something.

Comment: The fun part was noticing the black and white background that moves separately from the Taxi.  I think he was going for "effect"

Comment: LOL, I agree. The Cab wasn't even moving it seems. The smoke from the cigarettes were just hanging even though the windows were open. When Butch tossed the Gloves out of the cab, they made a definite thump on the ground. The black and white retro background added to the mystery of this scene, QT had to have done all this intentionally, this man leaves no detail to chance.

Comment: Definitely, it was a homage but I can't tell you to whom.